# "The Google Cloud SDK could not be found in the customary locations and no path was provided." Jenkins

Tags: google-app-engine, jenkins, gradle, sdk

I am very new to jenkins, but I have searched for an answer for this a couple of days now. I run jenkins on localhost:8080. I have written a program in Java which uses gradle to deploy to Google App Engine cloud. Now I wanted to use Jenkins to build my program in GIT. Building the program with gradle is fine. When I run

> ./gradlew appengineDeploy

in Execute Shell I get following:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':appengineDeploy'.
>
> The Google Cloud SDK could not be found in the customary locations and no path was provided.
>
> - Try:
>
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 9.571 secs
>
> Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
> Finished: FAILURE

When I run the code locally, without Jenkins, The Google Cloud SDk is found under:

> /Users/marioyoussef/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk

And it works perfect, but I have no idea how to load it to jenkins when executing ./gradlew appengineDeploy.

Comment: Is jenkins running under your userid?

Comment: I run jenkins on localhost:8080 and registered an account when setting up jenkins. I am not sure what you mean with running under userid

Comment: Well, the SDK appears installed under `marioyoussef`'s homedir, meaning that `marioyoussef` probably has the right environment setup correctly from the SDK installation process (likely via the dot-rc files). But the user running jenkins most likely doesn't have that. Check your dot-rc files for how does your userid locates the SDK (there are sample files for several shells in the SDK dir itself). Or plain insert the `bin` subdir of the SDK dir at the beginning of the jenkins user's PATH.

Answer (score 10):

Adding the following to the module's `build.gradle` might help:

```
appengine.tools.cloudSdkHome="/Users/marioyoussef/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk"
```

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/gradle-reference#global_properties:

> Optional property to configure the location of the Google Cloud SDK. Typically the plugin finds this in the Cloud SDK when it is installed with **gcloud components install app-engine-java**.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to tackle the issue.

1. Add a symlink/shortcut for Google Cloud SDK
   The cloud plugin in IDE searches for SDK in some custom locations such as `$HOME/google-cloud-sdk`. So you can add a symlink in this directory and point it to actual installed location.
   In your case a shortcut in `/Users/marioyoussef` named **`google-cloud-sdk`** and point it to `/Users/marioyoussef/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk`
2. Add a cloudSdkHome property in **build.gradle**, but this can be troublesome if you share it with others as the might have it on a different location. For that, you can just mention it in README for others to change it.
   Just add this line in app's build.gradle
   `appengine.tools.cloudSdkHome="/Users/marioyoussef/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk"`

Source: [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-plugins-core/issues/416#issuecomment-350181571)

Comment: Does your solution #1 work in Windows, MacOS, or Linux?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm working on Linux and it definitely worked.

Answer (score 0):

The cloud tries to find the Google Cloud sdk in a set of predefined directories. If it does not find it, it throws an error. 
What helped me was this:

**Adding a shortcut to the home directory solved my problem.**

Comment: Your answer as it's currently written is not very helpful. Please add more details. 1. List the predefined directories. 2. What's the name of your shortcut? 3. Where's it pointing to? 4. Does your solution work in Windows, MacOS, or Linux?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out @naXa for this. As I am newbie this really helps :)