# GCloud AppEngine under Eclipse doesn't start (Mac OS)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I want to run a GCloud App Engine (Spring Boot Application) in Eclipse under Mac OS. When I start the App Engine, I get the following error:

```
The Google Cloud SDK could not be found in the customary locations and no path was provided. -> [Help 1]
```

The SDK is installed, the installation path is set to the PATH variable. The app-engine-java component is also installed. Eclipse also finds the installed SDK and the Eclipse Plugin for Google Cloud is also installed.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: How are you starting the local server? Also, are you using [gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51029339/3058302)?

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following to the module's `build.gradle` might help:

```
appengine.tools.cloudSdkHome="/Users/marioyoussef/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk"
```

OR

Create a symlink inside your user folder to the installation folder of the GCloud SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it's working now.

Solution is to create a symlink inside your user folder to the installation folder of thew GCloud SDK.